# What does "_id" mean in this line of code?

Tags: c#

So when i read a tutorial i met that piece of code, and i didn't understand why does " T id" and why author after then write in class "id = _id"?

```
 class Account<T>
   {
    public T id { get; set; }
    public int Sum { get; set; }

    public Account(T _id)
    {
        id = _id;
    }
}
```

Comment: `id = _id` sets the value of the property `id` to the value of the parameter `_id`.

Comment: He needed a different name for the parameter to distinguish it from the property. But two things to note. Property names should be Upper case, which would already disambigutate the names. He could also named the parameter just `id` and do `this.id = id;`.

Comment: `T` is a generic type parameter. I think you are going to need to read up a bit more, this is all pretty basic stuff

Comment: It would be nice if you could state the reason for down voting the question. new contributors will get discouraged if their questions are downvoted without any valid comments. its bad for the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He is just naming the variables differently for ease of reading / understanding. What he does is, declaring a property of type `T` (generic type) with name `id` and accepting a value for that in the constructor using the variable `_id` also of type `T`. and assigning it to the `id` proprty. this can also be writter as below but for clarity of reading the above approach may be good.

```
class Account<T>
{

    public T id { get; set; }
    public int Sum { get; set; }

    public Account(T id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx man, I've often seen before, and didn't understand what that means, i guess that have a more sense them just for clarity

Answer (score -2):

So the Constructor is theroeticly (practicly) a Method, it takes Parameters.
So you can `new T(5)`.
The Class ITSELF has a Member which is "id", a variable which holds information AS LONG as the Object of this Class is not disposed.

Parameters of a Method are only Viable inside the Method, so _id is only Aviable in the Constructor.
If u want to Create a new Car with ID 5. The Object has to know that its ID 5.

So you Programmer, Create a Car with ID 5
T lambo = new T(5)

Now the Constructor Method has the _id = 5.

In the Constructor while constructing u Mark on the Car that its which it has been given
id = _id

now id = 5
and _id is gone after the constructor